# Why doesn't console.table work in Firefox?

Tags: javascript, debugging, firefox, web-console

Why doesn't console.table (or certain other console methods) work in Firefox, or return an error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firefox's built-in [Web Console](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Web_Console), ignores unknown console calls rather than throw an exception.  So while a normal call, e.g.

```
window.table()
```

or any unknown method of a normal object, you get something like:

```
[20:29:35.381] TypeError: window.table is not a function
```

However:

```
console.table({foo: 'bar'})
```

just returns undefined without doing anything, even though:

```
typeof console.table
```

returns:

```
"undefined"
```

Comment: Maybe acepting the answer?

Answer (score 0):

As an update, it works since Firefox 34, see:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/table